# Show a specific component based on Dynamic Angular Routing path

Tags: angular

My routes:

- `/dashboard`
- `/dashboard/view-all`
- `/dashboard/edit/:id`

Basically, I have a table in the `/dashboard/view-all` and for each row, I have an Edit Button to take me to the `/dashboard/edit/:id`, and it works fine.

The Problem: I can't show/hide the `EditComponent` according to the Dynamic Router. I usually show/hide Angular Component based on Router using something like this:

```html
<app-view-all *ngIf="route.url == '/dashboard/view-all'"></app-view-all>
```

For a dynamic router, when I am trying to write it like:

```html
<app-edit *ngIf="route.url == '/dashboard/edit/:id'"></app-edit>
```

It doesn't work, but it works when I change it to something like: `/dashboard/edit/26`. I am new to Angular, and I didn't find such a duplicate question on SOF, maybe it's a very basic Angular question? :D

Thank You!!

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg There's really nothing more than a routing file with the mentioned routes above, and all I need is the logic behind show/hide certain component in Angular for Dynamic Routing. If you think a Stackblitz might help, I would love to create it for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using `indexOf` JavaScript Method, and I consider it a hacky solution:

```html
<app-edit *ngIf="route.url.indexOf('/dashboard/edit/') >= 0" ></app-edit>
```

It returns `true` if the path has the `/dashboard/edit/` part, otherwise, it returns `false`.

**I do wonder; Is there a better, conventional solution?**

Comment: @AakashGarg Please post alternative, better answer. As described, my Angular knowledge, is pretty low, yet! :D

Comment: posted alternative above.

Answer (score 0):

Your Route Config should be like

```
{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
},
{
  path: 'dashboard/:section',
  component: DashBoardComponent
},
{
  path: 'dashboard/:section/:id',
  component: DashBoardComponent
}
```

In Dashboard.component.ts

```
public isEditing = false;
public editId;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe((param) => {
       isEditing = param.section==='edit';
       editId = param.id;
   });
}
```

In dashboard.component.html

```
<app-view-all *ngIf="!isEditing"></app-view-all>

<app-edit *ngIf="isEditing"></app-edit>
```